Understanding に挟まれる
I have trouble understanding the function of に in に挟まれる when 挟む is used in sense of this definition:

❶ 物を両側から押さえて動かないようにする。
「本を小脇に━」
「洗濯ばさみで衣類を━」
「ヘアピンで髪を━」
「毛虫を箸(はし)で━・んで捨てる」
語法:「二人組に━・まれて連れ去られる」「村は左右を山に━・まれている」など、受身で使うことも多い。

Based on what I know from the definition, XをYに挟む means to trap/sandwich X in Y. So it seems like に marks the location where an object gets trapped in.
Then Yに挟まれる means to get trapped in Y? ブロック塀に挟まれた路地 means a road that is sandwiched between block walls? Sometimes there are cases when に marks a passive agent like @aguijonazo mentioned? I suspect this に works in the same way as the one in に巻き込まれる.

挟まれる is a passive form. The agent of the action is marked by に in a passive sentence.

Generally speaking, the particle に can mark both:

the agent of a passive verb (≈ "by")
the destination or indirect object of an action (≈ "to/into")

This can sometimes lead to an ambiguity when に appears in a passive sentence. For example, 母に渡された手紙 can mean both "the letter passed to Mom" and "the latter passed by Mom", depending on the context. This phenomenon has been asked several times:

The meaning of ”あれは魔術師に与えられた祝福”
Confusing 届ける　受身 form
Particle に in passive sentences? あいつから、例の本が彼女に渡された

However, as far as 挟む is concerned, this is not really a problem. 母に渡された手紙 is ambiguous, but this is because when you say "AがXをYに渡す", both A and Y can be a person. This is not the case with 挟む.
When you say "AがXをYに挟む" or "BがXを挟む", A is a person, B is some visible (and usually rigid) object, but Y is a noun representing a tight space such as 小脇, 足の間 or 隙間. Therefore, when you see its passive version, "(Xが)◯◯に挟まれる", you can easily tell whether this ◯◯に is "by B" or "in Y" just by looking at whether ◯◯ is a "space".
In your example, ブロック塀 is not a space. It's a rigid object, and you cannot go inside it. Therefore, ブロック塀に挟まれた路地 only means "a narrow road squeezed by/between block walls", where ブロック塀 is the agent. However, when you say 本と本の間の隙間に挟まれた紙 ("a paper slipped in the gap between two books"), this に is indeed closer to "in(to)" rather than "by", because 隙間 is a noun that represents a narrow space.
